# Blender Geonodes - How to unparent geonodes particles from object so they aren't affected by the spawning object's movement?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to unparent geonodes particles from object so they aren't affected by the spawning object's movement? I have included a video to demonstrate my problem:

[image]

And a picture with my geonodes:
[image]
[image]

Instead of the particles movement being attached to the parent object that spawned them, I'd like them to be independent of the object's movement, if that makes sense.

Comment: the easy solution is use a "wrapper" object that doesn't move and use an object info set to reletive to bring that object in as reletive to the world origin (really the wrapper's origin).

Comment: @shmuel That worked well! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Shmuel answered, you need to leave the object that has the geonodes at the world center or static, and then use a Object info node to add an object 'spawner' that can move around set to relative.

Comment: yeah that is the simple solution. you could also use the object info node (and self object) to cancel transforms, but that isn't as simple to do.