# How to Simulate geo nodes Particles in World Space? or Atleast Fake it

Tags: geometry-nodes, world, transform-orientation, simulation-nodes

i have a geo nodes sim with two swords colliding  one is set as emitter other as collider but the particles are following emitter swords rotation  i have thought about locking the rotation vector to a ground plane but don't know about the locking the position after impact  if anyone know a effecient way to do it please do tell me

[image]

[image]

Here i want lock the position and rotation of particles on the imapact frame then let the physics sim happen

Comment: see here https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/309610/165102

Comment: *"- Doctor, when I do »this« it hurts. - Stop doing it."*   Just don't rotate and move your emitter. If you want to emit from a particular position, use "Object Info" node to read the current location of the object to emit from.